# XSD based binary serialisation

Tags: java, serialization, xsd, binary-serialization

Hello i am looking for an binary serialisation for java that:
- use xsd for schema
- output very small byte streams
- the byte stream should not contain the field names and data types
- pojos should be generated like it is possible gor jaxb
- nice to have: an implantation in java script

Do any some one know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an XSD schema, the conventional expectation is that you'd be serialising to/from XML. That's not a very small byte stream; plain text is quite inefficient for representing binary data (ints, floats, etc).

However there is an option. XSD schema and ASN.1 schema are interchangeable, more or less. There's even an official translation between the two defined by the ITU. There are tools that translate between the two.

Why is this relevant? Well, with ASN.1 you have access to a variety of different wire formats. There's a bunch of binary ones, as well as text ones (including, yes, XML and JSON). The important thing is that one of the binary ones is uPER (unaligned Packed Encoding Rules), which will use the bare minimum of bits to represent the data being sent.

For example, suppose that you'd got a class with an integer field, and you'd constrained its value to be between 0 and 7. uPER would use only 3 bits for that field.

What you can have is an XSD schema being i) tranlated to ASN.1 and compiled by an ASN.1 compiler (OSS), or ii) compiled directly by an ASN.1 compiler (Obj-Sys), producing Java POJO classes that can be serialised to/from ASN.1's uPER wireformat (and all the other binary formats, and XML and JSON too for that matter, depending on the ASN.1 compiler one's using). It's a similar way of working as with jaxb / xjc.

The tooling I've suggested in the previous paragraph requires, AFAIK, the ASN.1 proprietary compilers and tools from either Objective Systems (obj-sys.com) or OSS Nokalva (www.oss.com), and they're not free (n.b. I've been a customer of both, not otherwise associated with them). I think that there's a free online converter for XSD<-->ASN1 schema, and there are some free ASN1 compilers (though they commonly target C, not Java).

Links: [OSS's XSD translator](https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/xsdasn1/xsdasn1.html), [Objective System's Compiler reference for XSD translation](https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/acv73/CCppHTML/ch05.html), [OSS Java support](https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-java/asn1-java.html), [Obj-Sys's Java support](https://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Having wittered on about XSD, ASN.1, etc there are other options that might be usable but probably mean dropping the XSD schema and using something else.

**Google Protocol Buffers**

There are Java (and a load of others) bindings for Google Protocol Buffers, and GBP wireformat is binary. It's not as good as ASN.1's uPER for data size, but certainly smaller than XML text. See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial). It has its own schema language, and as far as I know there's no translator between XSD and GPB's.

**Capn Proto**

Another interesting option (see this [project](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto-java/)), again a binary format. It won't quite beat uPER for size, but it is fast to serialise / deserialise (or at least it is in C/C++). Again, I know of no translation between its schema language and XSD.